# Determining the remote port of the http request in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I want to know the remote port of the request to express web server. The api has mechanism to determine remote IP but I could not find a way to determine the port.

Comment: You set the port,so you know the port already when your API is hit by a request.

Comment: remote port not the server port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularly for node, the documentation for the http server component, under [event connection](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.25/api/http.html#http_event_connection) says:

> [Triggered] when a new TCP stream is established. [The] socket is an object of type
>   net.Socket. Usually users will not want to access this event. In
>   particular, the socket will not emit readable events because of how
>   the protocol parser attaches to the socket. The socket can also be
>   accessed at **`request.connection`**.

So, that means `request.connection` is a socket and according to the documentation there is indeed a [socket.remotePort](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteport) attribute which according to the documentation is:

> The numeric representation of the remote port. For example, 80 or 21.

So, I guess you should be able to get the remote address and port by accessing those attributes in your `request.connection.remoteAddress` and `request.connection.remotePort` or by subscribing to the event mentioned above.

Comment: request.connection seems deprecated